# How to correctly insert newline in nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to make a script that takes some rich text (html text) and transform it to regular text. What I want to do is replace all `<br>` tags with newline. I tried to do this with replace function:

```
set @rich_text_to_modify = replace(@rich_text_to_modify,'<br>', CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

The 
 tags get removed but newlines are not inserted. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that isn't inserting a new line? It works fine for me. For example `DECLARE @rich_text_to_modify nvarchar(MAX) = 'Hello<br>Goodbye';
SET @rich_text_to_modify = REPLACE(@rich_text_to_modify, '<br>', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));
PRINT @rich_text_to_modify;` returns 2 lines in the messages pane, `Hello` and `Goodbye`.

Comment: How did you determine that newlines are not inserted?

Comment: when nvarchar was updated I tried to copy it into editor to see if there are any line breaks but there wasn't any

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is your setting on SSMS, not that the data doesn't have a line break.

Go to: `Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server  -> Results to Grid  -> Retain CR/LF on copy or Save` and make sure the option is ticked.

Comment: For me, checking this option didn't work. I still get all text in one line, in spite of having many CR/FL characters in my text.

Comment: I actually very highly doubt that @SaeedNeamati . I suspect that the setting wasn't saved, or you're doing something *else*.

Comment: After checking the option, I found you have to start a new query window.  It doesn't seem to affect one that is already open.  It still shows as a space in the grid, but if you copy/paste it to Excel it will have the crlf.

Answer (score 6):

You absolutely sure that it doesn't work? I did a quick check in SSMS with two different ways of result presentation.

Test code:

```
declare @rich_text_to_modify as nvarchar(200) = N'line1<BR>line2';

select @rich_text_to_modify

set @rich_text_to_modify = REPLACE ( @rich_text_to_modify , N'<BR>' , NCHAR(13)+NCHAR(10))

select @rich_text_to_modify
```

Presenting results using **'Results to Grid (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)'**

[image]

Presenting results using **'Results to Text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)'**

[image]

As you can see your method works fine. In Grid end line characters are translated to spaces. Maybe there is a problem with the method you use for verification?