# SQL Server line break for CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query in CSV format, it is below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + [symbol], + ',' + [date] + ',' + [price]
        FROM csvFormatTable
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    ,2,200000
) 
AS CSV
```

and it mostly gives the correct result apart from the `','` at the end of the line but I do want to replace it with a line break. I've seen CHAR(10) and similar stuff like that but it does not give a line break but instead a `'#x0D'`. The result of the query above is what I have (without the char(10) stuff) below:

```
symbol,date,price,mikeCode,2019-04-10,50,mikeCode,2019-04-11,200,mikeCode,2019-04-12,10,
```

Where as it should be:

```
symbol,date,price
mikeCode,2019-04-10,50
mikeCode,2019-04-11,200
mikeCode,2019-04-12,10
```

It needs the line break so it can be readable as a CSV.

Comment: What is in csvFormatTable?

Comment: It's the table where It's like the CSV format, exmaple:

     [symbol]         [date]            [price]
1     mikeCode    2019-04-10    50

Comment: That doesn't makes any sense. You should really edit your question and post an example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2016- then use `(N)CHAR(13)` and `(N)CHAR(10)`. You'll then need to use `TYPE`, to avoid the escaping of the characters, and then `value` to get the values out.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + [symbol] + 
                     ',' + [date] + ',' + [price]
             FROM csvFormatTable
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,3,'') AS CSV;
```

If you *are* on SQL Server 2017+, you can use `STRING_AGG`

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ',' + [symbol] + ',' + [date] + ',' + [price],CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
FROM csvFormatTable --Untested
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4cf54c77fff057e794fd615ebe310ba)

Comment: Unfortunately neither are giving the line break when I paste the results into a CSV file. I was thinking this might be easier to do if I stringed the results and then tried to add the line break.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115490/how-to-correctly-insert-newline-in-nvarchar/53115559#53115559

Comment: That's because of your SSMS settings @Noobcoder , not the SQL.

Comment: I have enabled the tick box for `Retain CR/LF on copy or Save` but the `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` is still showing `#x0D`

Comment: @NoobCoder that is literally impossible with the code I've provided you. I'll post a DB fiddle later to confirm, but if you are getting escaped characters you've done something wrong.

Comment: @NoobCoder DB<>Fiddle added to confirm working as you want. If this isn't working, then, like I said, you've done something wrong. You'll need to show what you've done, so we can help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larnu I changed the settings in my SMSS (link on how to do this is here):
[How to correctly insert newline in nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115490/how-to-correctly-insert-newline-in-nvarchar/53115559#53115559)

And I just changed my query around a bit to get the wanted results to

```
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL =
    '
        DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @test = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CHAR(10) + [symbol] + '','' + [date] + '','' + [price], CHAR(13) ) FROM csvFormatTable)
        SELECT @test
    '

EXEC(@SQL)
```