# SQL Code on Multiple Lines instead of One Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table which acts like a code vault of sorts for an SSIS package.

| ID | SQL Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SELECT * FROM TBL1 |
| 2 | SELECT * FROM TBL2 |
| 3 | SELECT * FROM TBL3 |

When I copy and paste the code where ID = 1, I get the following SQL Code on 2 lines after I paste:

```
     SELECT *
     FROM TBL1
```

A co-worker trying to use the same table, copies and paste the code where ID = 1, he gets the following SQL Code on 1 line: `SELECT * FROM TBL1`

How do I get my co-worker (when they copy and paste the SQL code) to see the SQL code on 2 lines like I am? Is that an option within the settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly insert newline in nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115490/how-to-correctly-insert-newline-in-nvarchar/53115559#53115559)

Comment: What are you and you coworker pasting it into?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that their coworker doesn't have "Retain CR/LF on copy" switched on, @RBarryYoung .

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284582/3987784) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been solved in comments for this question. "Retain CR/LF on copy"  needed to be switched on. Thank you!